# 2d array with cells that can hold more than 1 value at index

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I need to produce a matrix with 4 rows and 4 columns. The thing is some of the cells need to hold more than one value. I'm not sure how to make this. Should I make another array, so `array [] value = {1,13};` and then put the index for this in my 2d array?

```
 Array [][] matrix = new Array [4][4];
 matrix [][]   =   {{ a,        b,       c,  d},
                    {{1,13},    10,      6,  8}, 
                    {{2,14},    11,      7,  9},
                    {{5,13,15}, {12,10}, 4,  4} };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 3D array instead.

I'm not sure if you are storing objects or primitives in your array, but let's assume primitives (it doesn't really make a difference) :

```
int[][][] matrix = new int [4][4][];

matrix[1][1] = new int [] {10};
matrix[2][0] = new int [] {2,14};
matrix[3][0] = new int [] {5,13,15};
```

Or you can initialize it directly :

```
 int [][][] mat =   
     {{{0},      {0},     {0},  {0}},
     {{1,13},    {10},    {6},  {8}},
     {{2,14},    {11},    {7},  {9}},
     {{5,13,15}, {12,10}, {4},  {4}}};
 System.out.println (Arrays.deepToString (mat));
```

Note that I changed the single values to arrays of length 1 and the characters of the first row to {0}, since this is an `int` array.

Output (I added some line breaks and spaces for the sake of readability) :

```
[[[0],         [0],      [0], [0]], 
 [[1, 13],     [10],     [6], [8]], 
 [[2, 14],     [11],     [7], [9]], 
 [[5, 13, 15], [12, 10], [4], [4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks I would have gone down a completely different route if it wasn't for this.

Comment: @Will What data do you want to put in the array? Primitives? Objects? In your code you wrote `Array`, so if that's your real code, the compiler expects a class called `Array`.

Comment: I just changed the data type of the array to char and it works fine now. I'm making a NFA table so I needed a row for symbols and the other rows for states. Thanks for the help.